# sharing c code variable between two directories Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

My current make to to SDK got a error which says `wan_name` is not declared in `linux-2.6.21/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_core.c`.
It is declared as `extern` in `nf_conntrack_core.c`

I am reconfiguring Linux kernel as per my requirements.

While tracing wan_name variable I found it is declared and used in `linux-2.6.21/net/ipv4/ip_tables.c` and also declared `extern` and used in `linux2.6.21/net/ipv4/ip_conntrack_core.c`

So it is like `wan_name` is declared in `net/ipv4/` directory inside `.c` file and used as **extern** by other `.c` file in same directory. But `net/netfilter/` directory `.c` files want to access that variable.

is that possible ?

what could be best solution to fix this bug ??

As per my knowledge **extern** allow you to access global variable declared in the same directory `.c` files. what if other directory `.c` file want to access that variable.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the global variable is defined in other directory or same. While linking if `extern` variable declaration in a compilation unit  matches with definition with **exact same type** in same or different compilation unit, it would link. (1) So you need to check whether the type of declaration and definition match exactly or not. (2) Is module `nf_conntrack_core` getting linked with module `ip_tables`. If not, you will see a linker error.

Comment: Yes. This error is linking error. so **extern** keyword is not enough for global variable in different directory. `net/built-in.o: In function 'nf_conntrack_in' : undefined reference to 'wan_name' ` is exact error line. iptables may be linked later than netfilter module object file so this error or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought is not correct . You can you can use

```
extern
```

even if the c files are in different directory.